# Need to keep a URL hidden from the user, can I return the results of the HTTP request as an ActionResult?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, http, actionresult

In order to access a vendor resource (externally hosted) I have a URL that makes a request which contains authentication credentials. The URL is built dynamically, but I don't want it present in the user's browser. Instead, I'd like to build the URL, send the request using an HttpWebRequest, get the results, and then return those results from the controller action to the user in the browser via an AJAX call.

I feel like I have done this before and I already know how to make HTTP requests from within the server, however I am having trouble determining which type of ActionResult to use.

Comment: I'm having a really hard time following your train of thought... Where is the URL built? The client or server?

Comment: URL is never exposed to the client, server will make the request using HttpWebRequest and I want the response returned to the user.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you could just use a normal ActionResult to handle this.  If I understand your question, the workflow would be something along these lines...

**View Model**

```
public ResponseModel(){
     public string response {get;set;}
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult GetOutsideResults(){
    //make HttpWebRequest
    var model = new ResponseModel();
    model.response = ResultsFromWebRequest();
    return View(model);
}
```

**View**

```
@Html.Raw(model.response);
```

You can do the same thing with an Ajax request and a partial view as well.  This keeps the credentials on the server and provides a method to return the HTML results. I think you could use a JSON result as well and parse using JQuery.

**Controller**

```
public JsonResult GetOutsideResults(){
    //make HttpWebRequest
    return Json(ResultsFromWebRequest());
}
```

**View**

```
$ajax({...
     success:  function(data){
        $("#targetDiv").html(data);
     });
```

Comment: @Tommy Did you mean `return Json(...)`?

Answer (score 0):

you can use a hidden iframe to make the post and retrieve the response and show it to the user.

Comment: Whether I use an iframe or an AJAX call I am still making a call to my Controller Action which will make the ultimate request and return the results, the question is which ActionResult type is used to return an http web response from the Action?